# weird behaviour of terminal in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when i try to execute any command in vscode, for some reason, it opens a particular file. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with WSL 2

For example, when i do pip freeze it opens a file with the following content:

```
#!/home/leonardofr/documents/api_flask/flask-project/project/venv/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Another example:

When i try to run a flask app with `flask run` it opens another file:

```
#!/home/leonardofr/documents/api_flask/flask-project/project/venv/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from flask.cli import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the WSL extension in vscode.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried to mark it as solved but i got an error message that i had to wait some time before marking it as solved ( i think it was to wait 2 days). Then i forgot.. So thanks for the reminder.